# onclick event for a dynamic element

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic button which gets added by html attribute:

**EDITED:**

```
$("#gallery").html("<button id='" +img_name.substring(img_name.indexOf("uploaded_images")) 
    + "' onclick='testrf('test')' 
    class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete_btn' >Delete</button>");
```

I have my function as:

```
function testrf(param)
{
    alert(param);
};
```

but it gives me testrf not defined, is that because my element is added dymanicaly?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of inline JS, why not use event delegation with `.on()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an entire practice that says it's a bad idea to have inline functions/styles.

Just use jQuery.

JS

```
$('button').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);})
```

HTML

```
 <button id='1234' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete_btn' >Delete</button>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kfYQ/1/

Comment: Nice man! You solved my problem; I couldn't vote up your answer:( But I would like to know why my code does not work either :(

Comment: It's probably a scope issue. The test function you just defined is  most likely local to the scope of an anonymous function and not global.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with the function globally defined: http://jsfiddle.net/9JXss/

Comment: Also, if you are adding elements dynamically, make sure you use the on function coupled with your click so as to bind the new elements: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

It is not coming out as a function.  It looks right here, but there may be a missing semicolon right before the function is defined.  It is looking for testrf rather than defining it as a function.  Syntax check your entire page, not just the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="testrf('test')"
```

You should use different quotes

Comment: hey man; I'm using html attribute and adds it dynamically; so I passed all of the button tag I mentioned inside: $('#content').html("ALL OF MY BUTTON TAG WITH THE SYNTACX MENTIONED GOES HERE");